# Saving objects with many elements in Fabric.js canvas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, fabricjs

I'm working on a Rails app with image manipulation on a Fabric.js canvas and I want to implement a speech bubble much like in this post: [Speech bubbles in Canvas/FabricJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62706613/speech-bubbles-in-canvas-fabricjs). One of the answers gives a Javascript code that worked neatly with minimal changes until I tried to save the changes made to the image in the canvas. The speech bubble is made of 5 elements: a textbox, a rect, 2 polys and a handle, all displaying in relation to one another, with the 2 polys being able to be moved independently from the rect and the textbox. When I save the changes after I place the speech bubble somewhere on the canvas, the elements are not saved in relation to one another, but each is saved as a unique canvas object and they loose their original placement.

I tried to group them together, but that makes it so that you can't move the polys independently and it generally ruins the speech bubble layout. What I really need is to have an event listener in one of the elements to toggle the display of the speech bubble, but I run into the same saving issues when I try to do that. In another answer in the same post, another user said they had trouble storing and loading the canvas data and they offered a solution, but I was not able to implement it successfully since any change I make to my save method makes the canvas completely unresponsive and all the other unrelated objects that were already present never display.

```
function saveCanvas(canvas, formInputField) {
  delete canvas.backgroundImage;
  formInputField.value = JSON.stringify(canvas);
}
```

```
function initializeFabricCanvas(canvasContainer, backgroundImageElement, canvasAsJSON) {
  let canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasContainer.id);

  enableHighlightDestroy(canvas);
  enableZoom(canvas);
  enablePan(canvas);
  enableNumber(canvas);
  enableComment(canvas);

  loadSavedCanvas(canvas, canvasAsJSON);
  let canvasSize = loadImageIntoCanvas(canvas, backgroundImageElement);
  resizeCanvasToImage(canvasContainer, canvas, canvasSize);

  document.getElementById("addCommentButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log("addCommentButton clicked");
    enableComment(canvas);
  });

  return canvas;
}
```

```
function loadSavedCanvas(canvas, canvasAsJSON) {
  if (canvasAsJSON.trim() !== "") {
    canvas.loadFromJSON(canvasAsJSON);
  }
}
```

```
function enableComment(canvas) {
  var boxPadding = 16;
  var arrowWidth = 16;
  var strokeWidth = 2;
  var handleSize = 24;

  var textbox = new fabric.Textbox("Your comment text goes here", {
    left: 200,
    top: 80,
    width: 180,
    fontSize: 16,
    originY: "center",
    originX: "center",
  });

  var setCoords = textbox.setCoords.bind(textbox);
  textbox.on({
    moving: setCoords,
    scaling: setCoords,
    rotating: setCoords,
  });

  textbox.lastLeft = textbox.left;
  textbox.lastTop = textbox.top;

  var handle = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: "transparent",
    left: 128,
    top: 160,
    width: handleSize,
    height: handleSize,
    hasRotatingPoint: false,
    hasControls: false,
    originY: "center",
    originX: "center",
  });

  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: "white",
    stroke: "black",
    strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
    rx: 8,
    ry: 8,
    objectCaching: false,
  });

  var poly = new fabric.Polygon(
    [
      { x: 0, y: 0 },
      { x: 1, y: 1 },
      { x: 1, y: 0 },
    ],
    {
      fill: "white",
      stroke: "black",
      strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
      objectCaching: false,
    }
  );

  var poly2 = new fabric.Polygon(
    [
      { x: 0, y: 0 },
      { x: 1, y: 1 },
      { x: 1, y: 0 },
    ],
    {
      fill: "white",
      objectCaching: false,
    }
  );

  // Create an asterisk at the tip of the handle
  var asterisk = new fabric.Text('*', {
    fontSize: 26,
    fill: 'red',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'bottom',
    selectable: false,
    evented: false,
  });

  canvas.add(poly, rect, poly2, textbox, asterisk); // Add the asterisk to the canvas

  canvas.add(handle).setActiveObject(handle);
  canvas.on("after:render", updateBubble);
  updateBubble();

  function updateBubble() {
    console.log("Updating Bubble...");
    var x = textbox.left;
    var y = textbox.top;

    var bound = textbox.getBoundingRect();
    rect.left = bound.left - boxPadding;
    rect.top = bound.top - boxPadding;
    rect.width = bound.width + boxPadding * 2;
    rect.height = bound.height + boxPadding * 2;

    if (x !== textbox.lastLeft || y !== textbox.lastTop) {
      handle.left += x - textbox.lastLeft;
      handle.top += y - textbox.lastTop;
      handle.setCoords();
      asterisk.left += x - textbox.lastLeft; // Move the asterisk with the handle
      asterisk.top += y - textbox.lastTop;
      asterisk.setCoords();
    }

    var halfPi = Math.PI / 2;
    var angleRadians = Math.atan2(handle.top - y, handle.left - x);
    var offsetX = Math.cos(angleRadians + halfPi);
    var offsetY = Math.sin(angleRadians + halfPi);

    poly.points[0].x = handle.left;
    poly.points[0].y = handle.top;
    poly.points[1].x = x - offsetX * arrowWidth;
    poly.points[1].y = y - offsetY * arrowWidth;
    poly.points[2].x = x + offsetX * arrowWidth;
    poly.points[2].y = y + offsetY * arrowWidth;

    var halfStroke = strokeWidth / 2;
    poly2.points[0].x = handle.left;
    poly2.points[0].y = handle.top;
    poly2.points[1].x = x - offsetX * (arrowWidth - halfStroke);
    poly2.points[1].y = y - offsetY * (arrowWidth - halfStroke);
    poly2.points[2].x = x + offsetX * (arrowWidth - halfStroke);
    poly2.points[2].y = y + offsetY * (arrowWidth - halfStroke);

    // Position the asterisk at the tip of the handle
    asterisk.left = handle.left;
    asterisk.top = handle.top - handle.height / 2;

    // Adjust the position with offsets
    var asteriskOffsetX = 0; // adjust as needed
    var asteriskOffsetY = 32; // adjust as needed
    asterisk.left += asteriskOffsetX;
    asterisk.top += asteriskOffsetY;

    textbox.lastLeft = x;
    textbox.lastTop = y;
  }
}
```

The asterisk is where I'm trying to add the event listener for the display toggle, but I can't make the speech bubble be saved and functional in the first place.

If anyone can offer suggestions it would be a huge help. Sorry if this post is redundant but I was not able to implement the saving and loading solution even with help from others.

Answer (score 0):

idk your fabricJS version but you could try to save your canvas like this :

```
canvas.toObject(propertiesToInclude)
```

propertiesToInclude as an array of the different (default or custom) properties you need to export :

```
export const propertiesToInclude = [
  'id', 
  'name', 
  'type',
  'isShow',
  'isCheck',
  'color', 
  'axis',
  'cropKey', 
  'cropPath', 
  'cropSize', 
  'fill',
  'selectable',
  'evented',
  'fillType', 
  'fillURL', 
  'fillRepeat', 
  'lockMovementX', 


  // Custom properties
  'myCustomProperties',


]
```